# Error when connecting nesjs app to SQL Server Express : failed to connect to localhost:1433 - self signed certificate

Tags: nestjs, sql-server-express

I am trying to connect my nestjs app to SQL Server Express, but I get this error:

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - self signed certificate

Note: port 1433 is open and I am able to connect via SSMS:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mssql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 1433,
      username: 'sa',
      password: '<mypassword>',
      database: 'test',
      entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}']
    })
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this **trustServerCertificate: true**

```html
@Injectable()
export class TypeOrmConfigService implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigrationService) {}

  createTypeOrmOptions(connectionName?: string): TypeOrmModuleOptions | Promise<TypeOrmModuleOptions> {
    return Promise.resolve<TypeOrmModuleOptions>({
      type: 'mssql',
      name: connectionName,
      host: this.configService.dbHost,
      port: this.configService.dbPort,
      username: this.configService.dbUsername,
      password: this.configService.dbPassword,
      database: this.configService.dbName,
      entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: true,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      options: {
        encrypt: true,
      },
      extra: {
        validateConnection: false,
        trustServerCertificate: true,
      },
    });
  }
}
```